# How to consume SOAP Webservice in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, web-services, soap

I want to consume the below web service by using angularjs $http service,

[image]

I tried the following code,

```
               $scope.btnSignIn =  function(){
                   var soapRequest = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"'+
                        'xmlns:v="http://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/ditws/TaxCredMismatch/v_1_0">'+
                        '<soapenv:Header/>'+
                        '<soapenv:Body>'+
                        '<v:getTaxCredMismatchRequest>'+
                        '<LoginInfo>'+
                        '<userName>AJAPA5685E</userName>'+
                        '<password>pass123</password>'+
                        '</LoginInfo>'+
                        '<UserInput>'+
                        '<panNo>AJAPA5685E</panNo>'+
                        '<asseessmentyear>2014-15</asseessmentyear>'+
                        '</UserInput>'+
                        '</v:getTaxCredMismatchRequest>'+
                        '</soapenv:Body>'+
                        '</soapenv:Envelope>';
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/eFilingWS/ditws/getTaxCredMismatchRequest.wsdl',                            
                        data: soapRequest,
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}                            
                    }).success(function(data,status, headers, config) { 
                        console.log(data);

                    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config,statusText) {

                    });                       
               };
```

but getting the response as

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/eFilingWS/ditws/getTaxCredMismatchRequest.wsdl. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
```

please let me know what wrong I did.

Comment: You need to enable CORS on the server side

Comment: I'm running this code from localhost and enable CORS using chrome extension CORS Toggle

Comment: Gulp or grunt config proxy so u dont have cors problem an call serwer from it